# Can you remove empty cell in SSRS matrix

Tags: reporting-services

I am just working on creating a matrix report in SSRS and when I create the report it contains loads of blank cell, I was wondering if there was a way to remove cells.

The data using is:

```
Topic        SupTopic        Keyword
A            1               Test1
B            1               Test3
A            2               Test2
B            2               Test1
A            3               Test1
B            2               Test2
A            1               Test3
A            2               Test1
B            3               Test2
```

And the report looks like this

```
         A                             B
1        2        3        1        2        3
Test1
                           Test3
         Test2
                                    Test1
                 Test1
                                    Test2
Test3
         Test1
                                              Test2
```

and I a would like it to look like this

```
         A                             B
1        2        3        1        2        3
Test1    Test2    Test1    Test3    Test1    Test2
Test3    Test1                      Test2
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by creating a Row number in my sql query that is partition by topic and subtopic. Then used the row number in the row for SSRS matrix.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Filter tab in the Dataset Properties form.  Create new filter and set Expression as boolean coombination of your columns.